# spring-mvc 3.0.5: what's the preferred way to instantiate the JPA entity manager

Tags: java, spring, jpa, dependency-injection, persistence

My current working code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TT-SpringMVCPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

I would like to replace that with something like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "TT-SpringMVCPU")
private EntityManager _entityManager;
```

When I try that, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'showController': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'TT-SpringMVCPU' is defined
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:341)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
...
```

What did I forget to configure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Spring reference manual: [Three options for JPA setup in a Spring environment](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-setup)

Answer (score 2):

> What did I forget to configure?

Well, you didn't show anything :) Anyway, [Using JPA in Spring without referencing Spring](http://blog.springsource.com/2006/08/07/using-jpa-in-spring-without-referencing-spring/) shows one way to do things:

> #### Configuration
>
> - `LocalEnityManagerFactoryBean` to create the `EntityManagerFactory`
> - `JpaTransactionManager` to manager JPA transactions
> - `<tx:annotation-driven />` to tell Spring to look for `@Transactional`
> - Your bean definition!
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
>     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
>     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
>     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
>     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
>
>     <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
>         class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean" />
>
>     <bean id="productDaoImpl" class="product.ProductDaoImpl"/>
>
>     <bean
>         class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
>
>     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
>         <property name="entityManagerFactory"
>             ref="entityManagerFactory" />
>     </bean>
>
>     <tx:annotation-driven />
>
> </beans>
> ```
>
> That's it. Two annotations and four
>   bean definitions.

Have a look.

#### See also

- [Chapter 13. Object Relational Mapping (ORM) data access](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html)

  - [13.5. JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa)